# $|z| = e^x, arg(z) = y$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In introducing complex analysis, my instructor made the following assertion:

> Let $w = x + iy$ and suppose $e^w = z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We have
>
> $z = e^w = e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$,
>
> so $|z| = e^x, arg(z) = y$

I'm confused as to how we went from

$z = e^w = e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$

to

$|z| = e^x, arg(z) = y$.

Since this is an introduction to complex analysis, I have no understand of complex analysis beyond the most basic concepts. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this and help me understand it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, we can only conclude that $y \equiv \arg z \pmod {2 \pi}$. We can get around this by making a choice of branch of $\arg$ and restricting the choice of $w$ accordingly.

Comment: @Travis Indeed. In this case, according to my instructor, we have $arg(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$, which is in accordance with our chosen branch: $\{ x + iy \mid x \in \mathbb{R}, -\pi < y \le \pi \}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$
|z| = |e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)| = |e^x||\cos y + i \sin y| = e^x(\cos^2y + \sin^2 y )^{1/2} = e^x  
$$

As for the argument, remember to calculate both the imaginary and real part of $z$ and form the ratio

$$
\Re(z) = e^x\cos y ~~~\mbox{and}~~~\Im(z) = e^x\sin y 
$$

Therefore

$$
\tan\arg(z) = \frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}=\frac{e^x\sin y}{e^x\cos y} = \tan y  ~~~\therefore~~~ \arg(z) = y
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have remembered that the absolute value of the product is equal to the product of the absolute values. Thanks again!